# How to make 'Always on Visible Workspace' for some applications permanent on Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME

Tags: workspaces, window-manager, gnome-shell

In KDE I could set windows from some applications to be '**Always on Visible Workspace**' permanently after restarts.

How do I do this to some applications  like Slack in latest Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME shell?